# On the smallest solution of a linear congruence

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-number-theory, congruences

I have the following question. First, consider the following congruence for primes $p\geq 5$:

$24x\equiv -1\;(\mbox{mod}\;p)$.

The smallest $x$, that is, $1\leq x\leq p-1$ for which the above congruence is true is $\dfrac{p^2-1}{24}-p[p/24]$, where $[.]$ is the integral part. Is there any explicit form (similar to the one above) of smallest $x$ for a general congruence: $ax\equiv b\;(\mbox{mod}\;p)$ for primes $p$, $(p,ab)=1$ and fixed $a, b$?

Any insight or comment is highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure there's any explicit form for a solution, even if you don't insist on it being the smallest.

Comment: "Explicit form" is a subjective term. At any rate, one can calculate the smallest solution of $ax\equiv b\pmod{b}$ quickly, using the Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: Adding on to @GHfromMO 's comment, it then isn't hard to do the Euclidean algorithm for *every* remainder modulo $b$, and so find a general formula once given $p$. It may be worth looking into whether there is a simple-ish formula with $p$ as an input.